# New to Java please help.form n servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets

Hi all when I run my servlet which contains a form and click submit I get the following error, I cannot find the error in my code but there is obviously one. Otherwise when I click submit the following appears in the Eclipse console:

```
ss
ss
zz@z.com
56464
asdcity
pen
null
22
Done1
Failed
```

There are two problems in here. First, null value is retrieved for payment mode. Second, insertions in database fails.

**Form :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="SaveServlet">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    Email ID:<input type="text" name="email_id"><br>
    Phone number:<input type="text" name="phone_number"><br>
    Address:<input type="text" name="address"><br>
    Purchasing Item:<input type="text" name="purchasing_item"><br>
    Payment Mode: <select name="paymentment_mode">
<option>Visa</option>
<option>Master</option>
<option>Mastro</option>
<option>Amex</option>
</select><br>
    Card number:<input type="text" name="card_number"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet :**

```
package myPack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
/**
* Servlet implementation class SaveServlet
*/
public class SaveServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public SaveServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws        ServletException, IOException {

        String s1=request.getParameter("firstname");
        System.out.println(s1);

        String s2=request.getParameter("lastname");
        System.out.println(s2);

        String s3=request.getParameter("email_id");
        System.out.println(s3);

        String s4=request.getParameter("phone_number");
        int s41=Integer.parseInt(s4);
        System.out.println(s41);

        String s5=request.getParameter("address");
        System.out.println(s5);

        String s6=request.getParameter("purchasing_item");
        System.out.println(s6);

        String s7=request.getParameter("payment_mode");
        System.out.println(s7);

        String s8=request.getParameter("card_number");
        int s81=Integer.parseInt(s8);
        System.out.println(s8);

        String c="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        System.out.println("Done1");


        Connection con=null;

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Done2");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(c, "root", "MyNewPass");
            System.out.println("Done3");

            PreparedStatement ps=null;
            System.out.println("Done4");

            String qs = "insert into table1 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(qs);
            ps.setString(1,s1);
            ps.setString(2,s2);
            ps.setString(3,s3);
            ps.setInt(4,s41);
            ps.setString(5,s5);
            ps.setString(6,s6);
            ps.setString(7,s7);
            ps.setInt(8,s81);
            System.out.println("Success");
            ps.execute();
            con.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Failed");}}
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting ??? , any exception or something ??

Comment: Could put e.printStackTrace(); in your catch ;), also pay attention to my answer.

Comment: In the catch block, use `System.out.println("Failed: " + e.toString());` for getting more information. Even more: `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is breaking at the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` line. Make sure you have included the MySQL JDBC jar file inside your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Here is a link you can download the right version :

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: You can read in the question that null is inserted so no problem with the data base.

Comment: You are right. So, I don't understand why question says null is inserted.

Comment: Make me remember how I was 10 years ago :)

Comment: i guess that will fix the prob...i downloaded the file can u pls tel me how can i insert it ..im using ecplise...thnx ;-)

Comment: In Eclipse you will need to add it in the *lib* dir of the project.

Comment: yes i did it....but the payment mode value is set to null ....in the drop down menu i selected visa

Comment: i changed it to name instead of using id...now it works fine...

Comment: Excellent! Upvote appreciated :)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie:I know bro...I'm stuck with basics.... ;-( Tnx for d help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Payment Mode: `select name="paymentment_mode"`

```
String s7 = request.getParameter("payment_mode");
System.out.println(s7);
```

`paymentment_mode` is not the same as `payment_mode`

also in getting values in dropdown use this:

and change this `select name="paymentment_mode"` into `select id="paymentment_mode"`

```
var s7 = document.getElementById("payment_mode"); 
var strUser = s7.options[s7.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: You are also mixing "payment_mode" with "paymentment_mode". I think that the error is there. Also, if you change "name" for "id" you will not get the value of "paymentment_mode" in the servlet. For that you need "name". Moreover, no JS code is necessary at all. Selected value form drop-downs will be sent automatically in the request.

Comment: it gives me an error as var is not resolved!!!!document not resolved..

Comment: try adding 

<script> 
var s7 = document.getElementById("payment_mode"); 
var strUser = s7.options[s7.selectedIndex].text;
</script>

or try what @jddsantaella said
select name="payment_mode"

String s7 = request.getParameter("payment_mode");
System.out.println(s7);

Comment: i changed it to name instead of using id...now it works fine

Comment: Hey guys, you can use "name" and "id" attributes at the same time ;-) But, anyway, not any JS is necessary as I said.